# HTML5 drag drop as form

Tags: html

I've had a look around and I'm wondering this is possible with HTML5 drag and drop.

I want to have 3 sections, 1 section with images of guys for example, 1 section with images of girls, and 1 section that I can drag 1 guy and 1 girl into. Once two people have been dragged into this section then a submit button is pressed and it treats it like a form and pass through an ID of the guy and ID of the girl to be processed.

My HTML looks like this

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="guy.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="200" height="200">
<img id="drag2" src="girl.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="200" height="200">
```

Would img id be a place where I could set an ID for the image?
How do I incorporate a form into the div1 part?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with jQuery's submit. http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit please? I'm unsure what you mean.

Comment: After you've dropped what you were dragging you can change the values of a form with jquery (`$('#field').val('value');`) and submit the complete form right after `$('#form').submit()`